# Minimize loops in reference to read/write operations

Tags: java, while-loop, minimize, do-while

the last thing I want to minimize today is code that contains while and do-while loops. Here is the original:

```
class Vereinfache3_edit { 

        public static void main(String [] args) {

           int c1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]) ;
           int c2 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]) ;
           int c3 = Integer.parseInt(args[2]) ;

/*  1 */           c1 += 7 ; 
/*  2 */           System.out.println( c1 ) ; 

/*  3 */       while (c1 % 8 != 0)
/*  4 */              if ( c1 % 16 == 0 ) ; 
/*  5 */              else
/*  6 */         do 
/*  7 */                 {
/*  8 */                    c1 += 7 ; 
/*  9 */                    System.out.println( c1 ) ; 
/* 10 */                    if ( c2 < c3 )
/* 11 */                       { c1 = c1+c1 ; 
/* 12 */                         c3 ++ ; 
/* 13 */                         c1 /= 2 ; 
/* 14 */                         c3 -= 1 ; 
/* 15 */                       }
/* 16 */                 }
/* 17 */                 while ( c1 % 8 != 0 ) ;

/* 18 */           c1 += 7 ; 
/* 19 */           System.out.println( c1 ) ; 
        }          

}  // end of class Vereinfache3
```

And here is my minimized version:

```
class Vereinfache3 { 

        public static void main(String [] args) {

               int c1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
               int c2 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]) ;
               int c3 = Integer.parseInt(args[2]) ;

               do{
                   c1 += 7 ; 
                   System.out.println( c1 ) ;               
               }while (c1 % 8 != 0);

/* 18 */       c1 += 7 ; 
/* 19 */       System.out.println( c1 ) ; 
        }          

}  // end of class Vereinfache3
```

It generates the same output for me. Do you see any errors or things that can be improved?

Especially this code seems to be tricky:

```
/*  3 */       while (c1 % 8 != 0)
/*  4 */              if ( c1 % 16 == 0 ) ; 
/*  5 */              else
/*  6 */          do{}
```

How do I deal with the while? What contains the while loop?

Comment: You don't see me to be using c2 and c3 anymore...if you are not using them in the later part of your code..you can remove those declarations..

Comment: Tried to explain a bit more now..check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your minimized version produces the same result as the original version, different outputs for your original solution and your minimized version are possible only in the case when                                           `c1 % 8 != 0 and c1 % 16 == 0`,
this case is impossible since all multiples of 16 are multiples 8 too..

Removing the unused declarations..is the only improvement I could suggest.
I do have a solution with less code..Not that it makes things any better...i don't like too many sysouts in code..:)

```
    int finalBound = ((c1 + 7) % 8 == 0) ? c1 + 7 : 8 * c1;
    for (; c1 <= finalBound; c1 += 7) {
        System.out.println(c1 + 7);
    }
```

Hope that helps.